# Change computername in Windows 10 network list

Tags: networking, windows-10, computer-name

When I open the Windows Explorer, and click on Network, I get a list of devices, printers, multimedia devices and under Computer I see the name of this computer. When I change the computer name via System settings, I see a different name, and changing that name doesn't change the given name in the devices list. The problem is that this name shows a partial password, which I don't want. In the image below the name is removed (green).

[image: Explorer]

(I'm realising that this might be another computer in the network...?)

How can I change this name?

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the computer name?

Comment: Yes I did restart. After doing so I checked the computername in systeminfo, and the name in the Explorer network list. No change. I'm beginning to suspect that it's another computer in the network.

Comment: You should try turning off network discovery and file sharing.

Comment: Problem is solved. This was another computer in the network. It took a while for me to realise that this was a list of computers in the network. I've changed the name and the problem is gone. I'll disable network discovery and file sharing as we don't need it.